# Next Keyboard Layout shortcut in Loki

Tags: release-loki, settings, keyboard-shortcuts

In Freya there was a "Next Keyboard Layout" option in Universal Access, but there is no such option in Loki settings. So, how to set this shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

You have *Switch layout* under the *Layout* tab.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but `Switch layout` has only a few default values. Especially, there are no `Super + Space` shortcut.

Comment: Super + Space is for the application menu